# Cloud Build dotnet fails - does not support targeting version

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Trying to build the aspnet core code with GCP Cloud Build.

the below `yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'microsoft/dotnet:sdk'
  entrypoint: 'dotnet'
  args: [ 'publish', 'folder/proj.csproj', '-c', 'Release' ]
```

fails with next errors:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.816/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(150,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.1.  Either target .NET Standard 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.1. [/workspace/folder/common.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.816/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1. [/workspace/folder/proj.csproj]
```

Is there a way to support different version of dotnet?

Comment: The file **proj.csproj** determines the framework. Look for **TargetFrameworkVersion**. In some cases, you can change it. In other cases, you must port your code to change the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#name) only pulls container images from certain registries, such as Docker Hub, Container Registry, Artifact Registry, etc. In this case, you would need to replace the image used in the `name` field in your script.

By using `microsoft/dotnet:sdk`, your script will be getting the default build which resulted in incompatibility. As per error it was using `2.1.816` whilst your application requires .NET 3.1.

With this, I recommend that you replace `microsoft/dotnet:sdk` with `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1`. Refer to [Docker Hub Container Image Library](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk) for more information.

Comment: yes, the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1` has worked.